# How does Selenium webdriver process communicate with Safari and Firefox?

Tags: selenium, websocket, webkit, protocols, gecko

So I've got a question on Selenium, specifically, the way it works with different browsers.
I know that when we talk about Chrome interactions we have 4 layers (roughly speaking):

**Layer 1** - our source code, that leverages all the functionality brought to us by Selenium library

**Layer 2** - Selenium library, that is basically making HTTP requests to the WebDriver process and parses its responses, returning back to Layer 1 convinient class instances, wrappers and abstractions.

**Layer 3** - is the WebDriver process running on host OS, interacting with Chrome instance by the means of websockets protocol and Chrome DevTools protocol running over it.

**Layer 4** - is the Chrome target browser instance.

So everything seems to be clear to me... unless we change target browser either to Firefox or Safari. I would assume we no longer use Chrome Devtools protocol for communication between webdriver process and browser instance.

**But then how does webdriver process communicate with Gecko- and WebKit-based browsers?**

Comment: Layer 2 is the driver sending requests to the browser... you can see the protocol described here:  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/  The driver then returns things to your code via the Selenium interfaces which all the drivers implement. (That's my understanding of it anyway...)

Comment: @pcalkins Right, I get this part where we have WebDriver protocol working over HTTP and webdriver process being basically a REST API. The part I don't get is how does webdriver process itself communicate with Safari/Firefox instance, because at this layer its definetely not a WebDriver protocol anymore. My guess it would have to do with native browser API calls, just the way it works with Chrome Devtools protocol.

Comment: Well basically the driver has access to it because the WebDriver launches the browser.  You could also build your own driver... anything that launches the browser can hook functions into it.  The browser's API must have specific pre-defined functions for  webdrivers to use(? using a specific sessionID?), but you could also write your own and inject handlers/calls to those functions on each pageload.